# How to add animation to changing image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some trouble adding an animation to the changing of the image on my website. If you click one of the images on the website a lightbox will open and you can click the thumbnails, arrows or arrowkeys to navigate through. When I try to add an animation by lowering the opacity and then removing it, everything stops working. The arrow keys stop working how they are supposed to when they reach the end (they are supposed to loop) and in the version I have gone back to it know longer works properly in safari, it reloads the images when you go into the lightbox. I suspect this has to do when the cloneNode but I don't know how to replace it.

Also, I am aware by cloning the images I am ending up with two elements of the same ID and am going to change this. Is there a way I can remove cloneNode and just style the images already present, or will I just ahve to replace the id's with classes?

The non-broken (apart from safari load issue) version can be found at: https://c6531672.000webhostapp.com/article.html

The broken version with the animation can be found below. The animation seems to overlap as well, so if anyone has any idea on how to fix that, it would be most appreicated.

```js
'use strict'

let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
let ids = "";
let boxID = "";
let imageID = "";
let id = 0;
let lightBoxOpen = false;

// Lightbox

let imageContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("image-container");
for (let i = 0; i < imageContainers.length; i++) {
    imageContainers[i].id = "image-container-"+i;
    let images = document.querySelectorAll("#image-container-"+i+" > img")
    for (let j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
        let id = i+"-"+j;
        let boxID = i;
        let imageID = j;
        images[j].id = id;
        images[j].addEventListener("click", function() {lightBox(id, boxID, imageID)})
    }
}

let whiteBackground = "";
let thumbnailsDisplay = "";
let clickedImage = "";
let activeImage = "";

let imageCloseBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("image-close-btn");
let leftArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("image-left-arrow-btn");
let rightArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("image-right-arrow-btn");

function lightBox(id, boxID, imageID) {
    imageCloseBtn[boxID].style.display = "flex";
    leftArrow[boxID].style.display = "flex";
    rightArrow[boxID].style.display = "flex";

    body.style.overflow = "hidden";

    clickedImage = document.getElementById(id);
    activeImage = clickedImage .cloneNode(true);
    activeImage.classList.add("active-image");

    if (lightBoxOpen == false) {
        whiteBackground = document.createElement("div");
        whiteBackground.classList.add("white-background");
        body.appendChild(whiteBackground);

        let numberOfImages = document.querySelectorAll("#image-container-"+boxID+" > img").length // imageContainers[boxID].children.length - 1; // To account for menu button

        thumbnailsDisplay = document.createElement("div");
        thumbnailsDisplay.classList.add("thumbnails");
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
            let thumbnail = imageContainers[boxID].children[i].cloneNode(true);
            if (thumbnail.id == clickedImage.id) {
                thumbnail.classList.add("active-thumbnail");
            }
            thumbnail.addEventListener("click", function(event) { // Need to pass event as parameter for firefox
                ids = event.target.id.split("-");
                id = event.target.id;
                boxID = ids[0];
                imageID = ids[1];
                removeActiveImage();
                document.getElementsByClassName("active-thumbnail")[0].classList.remove("active-thumbnail");
                event.target.classList.add("active-thumbnail");
                lightBox(id, boxID, imageID);
            });
            thumbnailsDisplay.appendChild(thumbnail);
        }
        imageContainers[boxID].appendChild(thumbnailsDisplay);
    }

    imageContainers[boxID].appendChild(activeImage); // Needs to be appended last as it is an extra child that doesn't need to be there

    lightBoxOpen = true;
}

function removeActiveImage() {
    activeImage.parentNode.removeChild(activeImage);
}

function destoryLightbox() {
    body.style.overflow = "visible";
    for (let i = 0; i < imageCloseBtn.length; i++) {
        leftArrow[i].style.display = "none";
        rightArrow[i].style.display = "none";
        imageCloseBtn[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    activeImage.parentNode.removeChild(activeImage);
    thumbnailsDisplay.parentNode.removeChild(thumbnailsDisplay);
    whiteBackground.parentNode.removeChild(whiteBackground);
    lightBoxOpen = false;
}

for (let j = 0; j < imageCloseBtn.length; j++) {
    imageCloseBtn[j].addEventListener("click", destoryLightbox);
}

for (let j = 0; j < Math.max(leftArrow.length, rightArrow.length); j++) {
    leftArrow[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
        changeSlide("left");
    });
    rightArrow[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
        changeSlide("right");
    });
}

function changeSlide(arrow) {
    activeImage.style.opacity = 0; // CHANGED
    setTimeout(removeActiveImage, 200); // CHANGED
    ids = activeImage.id.split("-");
    boxID = ids[0];
    if (arrow == "left") {
        imageID = parseInt(ids[1]) - 1;
        if (imageID == -1) {
            imageID = document.querySelectorAll("#image-container-"+boxID+" > img").length - 1;
        }
    } else if (arrow == "right") {
        imageID = parseInt(ids[1]) + 1;
        if (imageID == document.querySelectorAll("#image-container-"+boxID+" > img").length) {
            imageID = 0;
        }
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("active-thumbnail")[0].classList.remove("active-thumbnail");
    id = boxID+"-"+imageID;
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add("active-thumbnail"); // need to make everything a class so I don't have overlapping ids
    setTimeout(function() {lightBox(id, boxID, imageID)}, 201); // CHANGED
}

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    if (lightBoxOpen) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        switch (evt.key) {
            case "ArrowLeft":
                changeSlide("left");
                break;
            case "ArrowRight":
                changeSlide("right");
                break;
            case "Escape":
                destoryLightbox();
        }
    }
}

// Window and Content

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    contentScaler();
    // formFixer();
});

let scaleFactor = 100;

contentScaler();
// formFixer();

function contentScaler() {
    let html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    if (window.innerWidth > 1280 || scaleFactor != 100) {
        scaleFactor = window.innerWidth / 12.8;
        html.style.fontSize = scaleFactor + "%";
    } else {
        scaleFactor = 100;
        html.style.fontSize = scaleFactor + "%";
    }
}

// Form

// function formFixer() {
//     let emailInput = document.getElementsByClassName("email")[0];
//     let submit = document.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0];
    
//     let emailInputStyles = window.getComputedStyle(emailInput);
//     let emailInputHeight = 0;
    
//     emailInputHeight = emailInput.clientHeight;
//     emailInputHeight = (parseFloat(emailInputStyles.getPropertyValue("border-bottom-width")) + parseFloat(emailInputStyles.getPropertyValue("border-top-width")) + emailInputHeight) + "px";
//     submit.style.height = emailInputHeight;
// }
```

```css
:root {
    --background-color: #FFFFFF;
    --text-color: #000000;
    --light-text-color: rgb(137, 137, 137);
    --light-light-text-color: #EEE;
    font-size: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    src: url("AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf");
    font-family: "Avenir Bold";
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville';
}

nav .name {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    position: relative;
}

nav a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--text-color);
    height: 0.125rem;
    bottom: -0.1875rem;
    transition: width 200ms;
}

nav a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

/* GENERAL CONTENT STYLING */  

.content {
    margin: 0 4rem 1rem 4rem;
}

/* ARTICLE STYLYING */

.header-image {
    background-image: url("bioshock.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 70%;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: "Avenir Bold", Futura, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.content h1 , h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.content h1 {
    margin: 1.25rem 0 0.75rem 0;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 0.75rem 0;
    
}

p {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    line-height: 1.75;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: start;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}

.image-container > img:not(.active-image) {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: calc((100% - 1.5rem) / 3);
    margin: 0 0.75rem 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 13.5rem;
}

.image-container > img:nth-child(3):not(.active-image) {
    margin: 0;
}

.image-container > img:nth-child(n+4):not(.active-image) {
    margin: 0.75rem 0.75rem 0 0;
}

.image-container > img:nth-child(3n + 6):not(.active-image) {
    margin: 0.75rem 0 0 0;
}

.caption {
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    color: var(--light-text-color);
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
}

/* LIGHTBOX */

.white-background {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--background-color);

}

.active-image {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 80%;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: 200ms;
}

.thumbnails {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 20%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.thumbnails img {
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.thumbnails img:last-child {
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.image-close-btn, .image-left-arrow-btn, .image-right-arrow-btn, .photo-counter {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    z-index: 11;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;
}

.image-close-btn {
    right: 2.5%;
    top: 2.5%;
}

.image-close-btn img, .image-left-arrow-btn img , .image-right-arrow-btn img  {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}

.image-left-arrow-btn {
    left: 2.5%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.image-right-arrow-btn {
    right: 2.5%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.fa {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem !important; /* Required to overrule default size */
    margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
    transition: 200ms;
}

.fa:hover {
    color: #999;
}

.fa:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

/* FOOTER */

footer {
    background-color: var(--light-light-text-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2.5rem 4rem;
}

footer * {
    font-family: Futura, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

footer > * {
    width: calc((100%) / 3);
}

footer h1 {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

footer .form {
    display: flex;
}

footer .email, footer .submit {
    outline: none;
    border: 0.125rem solid var(--text-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: 0.35rem;
    background-color: transparent;
}

footer .email {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

footer .submit {
    border-left: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 20%;
    transition: 500ms;
    cursor: pointer;
}

footer .submit:hover {
    background-color: var(--text-color);
    color: var(--background-color);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game Review Article</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <span class="name">Game Review</span>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="article.html">Articles</a>
                <a href="">About / Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="header-image" alt=""></div>
            <h1>What made BioShock so great?</h1>
            <h3>Alex Stiles</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla porttitor, quam et feugiat consequat, turpis diam auctor tellus, quis luctus tellus massa eu dui. Morbi nec ex nec mi fermentum scelerisque sed a nunc. Sed et orci tempus, tincidunt felis et, facilisis nisl. Nulla sed venenatis odio. Maecenas commodo maximus dolor, ac rutrum purus placerat a. Nulla sed dui tristique risus hendrerit tristique. Fusce leo tellus, dapibus nec auctor non, lacinia eu odio. Suspendisse laoreet hendrerit pellentesque. Quisque suscipit nec neque aliquet venenatis. Nulla facilisi. Morbi risus arcu, iaculis at viverra vitae, feugiat quis odio. Pellentesque placerat molestie erat, et bibendum dolor consequat id.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque faucibus lacus rhoncus mi semper suscipit. Sed lobortis ullamcorper libero vel posuere. Pellentesque tortor mi, vehicula at lorem eget, ornare dapibus nisl. Donec finibus, odio tincidunt tempor aliquam, lectus neque pulvinar velit, vel pretium orci ipsum nec mauris. Nullam elit velit, vestibulum nec justo ac, tincidunt faucibus leo. Cras eu purus et ex finibus consectetur eget vitae ex. Vivamus quis elementum justo. Suspendisse vel ex at ligula finibus ornare. In imperdiet ut arcu et pellentesque. Vivamus finibus sit amet purus quis faucibus. Duis ut molestie ipsum. Morbi accumsan arcu leo, vitae bibendum metus pharetra at. Vestibulum quis finibus risus, ac blandit nibh. Sed pellentesque commodo auctor. Suspendisse arcu velit, consectetur et commodo mollis, pretium sed magna. Mauris non consequat arcu.</p>
            <h2>Ut porttitor dolor tincidunt</h2>
            <p>Suspendisse malesuada felis orci, ut porttitor dolor tincidunt in. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus consequat accumsan imperdiet. Phasellus sit amet felis diam. Fusce rutrum, nisl vel mattis sagittis, mi purus eleifend mi, et tristique tellus augue quis quam. Donec mi mauris, scelerisque auctor ultrices a, tempus sed velit. Sed in tempus lacus, vel viverra diam.</p>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="bioshock.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="welcome.png" alt="">
                <img src="andrew_ryan.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="lightbox-button image-close-btn">
                    <img src="close.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="lightbox-button image-left-arrow-btn">
                    <img src="left_arrow.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="lightbox-button image-right-arrow-btn">
                    <img src="right_arrow.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="caption">Some iconic photos from the first game</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla porttitor, quam et feugiat consequat, turpis diam auctor tellus, quis luctus tellus massa eu dui. Morbi nec ex nec mi fermentum scelerisque sed a nunc. Sed et orci tempus, tincidunt felis et, facilisis nisl. Nulla sed venenatis odio. Maecenas commodo maximus dolor, ac rutrum purus placerat a. Nulla sed dui tristique risus hendrerit tristique. Fusce leo tellus, dapibus nec auctor non, lacinia eu odio. Suspendisse laoreet hendrerit pellentesque. Quisque suscipit nec neque aliquet venenatis. Nulla facilisi. Morbi risus arcu, iaculis at viverra vitae, feugiat quis odio. Pellentesque placerat molestie erat, et bibendum dolor consequat id.</p>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p>Suspendisse malesuada felis orci, ut porttitor dolor tincidunt in. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus consequat accumsan imperdiet. Phasellus sit amet felis diam. Fusce rutrum, nisl vel mattis sagittis, mi purus eleifend mi, et tristique tellus augue quis quam. Donec mi mauris, scelerisque auctor ultrices a, tempus sed velit. Sed in tempus lacus, vel viverra diam.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla porttitor, quam et feugiat consequat, turpis diam auctor tellus, quis luctus tellus massa eu dui. Morbi nec ex nec mi fermentum scelerisque sed a nunc. Sed et orci tempus, tincidunt felis et, facilisis nisl. Nulla sed venenatis odio. Maecenas commodo maximus dolor, ac rutrum purus placerat a. Nulla sed dui tristique risus hendrerit tristique. Fusce leo tellus, dapibus nec auctor non, lacinia eu odio. Suspendisse laoreet hendrerit pellentesque. Quisque suscipit nec neque aliquet venenatis. Nulla facilisi. Morbi risus arcu, iaculis at viverra vitae, feugiat quis odio. Pellentesque placerat molestie erat, et bibendum dolor consequat id.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque faucibus lacus rhoncus mi semper suscipit. Sed lobortis ullamcorper libero vel posuere. Pellentesque tortor mi, vehicula at lorem eget, ornare dapibus nisl. Donec finibus, odio tincidunt tempor aliquam, lectus neque pulvinar velit, vel pretium orci ipsum nec mauris. Nullam elit velit, vestibulum nec justo ac, tincidunt faucibus leo. Cras eu purus et ex finibus consectetur eget vitae ex. Vivamus quis elementum justo. Suspendisse vel ex at ligula finibus ornare. In imperdiet ut arcu et pellentesque. Vivamus finibus sit amet purus quis faucibus. Duis ut molestie ipsum. Morbi accumsan arcu leo, vitae bibendum metus pharetra at. Vestibulum quis finibus risus, ac blandit nibh. Sed pellentesque commodo auctor. Suspendisse arcu velit, consectetur et commodo mollis, pretium sed magna. Mauris non consequat arcu.</p>
            <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig4" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig5" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig6" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig7" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig8" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig9" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig10" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig11" alt="">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/sig12" alt="">
                    <div class="lightbox-button image-close-btn">
                        <img src="close.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="lightbox-button image-left-arrow-btn">
                        <img src="left_arrow.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="lightbox-button image-right-arrow-btn">
                        <img src="right_arrow.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p>Pellentesque faucibus lacus rhoncus mi semper suscipit. Sed lobortis ullamcorper libero vel posuere. Pellentesque tortor mi, vehicula at lorem eget, ornare dapibus nisl. Donec finibus, odio tincidunt tempor aliquam, lectus neque pulvinar velit, vel pretium orci ipsum nec mauris. Nullam elit velit, vestibulum nec justo ac, tincidunt faucibus leo. Cras eu purus et ex finibus consectetur eget vitae ex. Vivamus quis elementum justo. Suspendisse vel ex at ligula finibus ornare. In imperdiet ut arcu et pellentesque. Vivamus finibus sit amet purus quis faucibus. Duis ut molestie ipsum. Morbi accumsan arcu leo, vitae bibendum metus pharetra at. Vestibulum quis finibus risus, ac blandit nibh. Sed pellentesque commodo auctor. Suspendisse arcu velit, consectetur et commodo mollis, pretium sed magna. Mauris non consequat arcu.</p>
            <div class="fa fa-facebook-square"></div>
            <div class="fa fa-twitter-square"></div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div>
                <h1>Newsletter:</h1>
                <form class="form" action="" method="post"><!-- Need to add action -->
                    <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" required> 
                    <button class="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                </form> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>We investigate the success behind the gaming world's most impressive feats. Sign up to the newsletter to stay in the loop.</p>
                <p>Copyright Someone</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to debug with this.
you can look at 277 lines,hope you find something handy.

https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/dev/dist/js/lightbox.js

thank you.